# How do I keep DOS batch echo on for parent script?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have a DOS batch file that I want echoing turned on.  However, this DOS batch file calls other batch files that then turn echoing off.  I don't mind that the child batch files turn echoing off for themselves.  But, is there any way for them not to affect the main script's echoing?

Answer (score 1):

Run them with cmd /c . In separate CMD instance.

Instead of:

```
call otherScript.bat
```

Use:

```
cmd /C otherScript.bat
```

This is of course only relevant if we are talking about Windows NT batches.

Comment: Good idea. Just be aware however that any EXIT commands would then only exit from the current shell, rather than the whole script.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately its not possible.  You would have to re-enable (@ECHO ON) echo after calling out to another batch file.

Answer (score 0):

No. Hovewer I'm not sure what will happen if you try to redirect output of a child script to a different stream.